# A graph based on sums in a sequence of numbers

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, matching-theory

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be numbers such that $1\geq x_1 \geq \cdots \geq x_n\geq 0$.

Construct a undirected graph in which the vertices are $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, and there is an edge between $x_i$ and $x_j$ iff $x_i+x_j\leq 1$.

This graph has a special structure: if it has an edge $(x_i,x_j)$, then it must have the edges $(x_{i'},x_{j'})$ for all $i'\geq i$ and $j'\geq j$.

Is there a term for this class of graphs?

I need the term in order to search for conditions for existence of perfect matchings in such graphs. So if you know of such conditions, this will be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Threshold Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_graph#Alternative_definitions)
The first alternative definition is basically the one you gave. There is a lot of stuff out there about threshold graphs

Comment: Thanks! Indeed any graph constructed by these two operations (adding an isolated vertex, adding a dominating vertex) can be represented as a "number graph" as follows: (1) Initialize $w = 1/2$. (2) If the next vertex is isolated, give it weight $1-w$.  (3) If the next vertex is dominating, give it weight $w$. (4) Let $w := w/2$. 
For the example graph in the Wikipedia page, the weights will be: $1/2, 3/4, 7/8, 15/16; 1/32; 63/64, 127/128; 1/256$.
I still have not found the opposite direction: given a "number graph", how do I find the sequence of operations?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi either x_1 is isolated or x_n is adjacent to everything.

Comment: @BobKrueger Ah, I see: the sequence is constructed from the end. So if $x_1$ is isolated, it must be the last in the sequence, and we construct recursively the sequence for $x_2,\ldots,x_n$; otherwise, $x_n$ must be the last in the sequence, so we construct recursively the sequence for $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask for perfect matchings, we should only consider when $n$ is even. I claim that a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a perfect matching is that $x_i + x_{n+1-i} \leq 1$ for all $i \in [n]$.

The condition is clearly sufficient, so we focus on necessity. Suppose there exists $i \leq n/2$ such that $x_i + x_{n+1-i} > 1$. Then the neighbors of each of $x_1, \dots, x_i$ are contained in $\{x_n, \dots, x_{n+2-i}\}$. This is a set of size $i$ whose neighborhood has size $i-1$, so there can be no perfect matching.

One should also be able to give a formula for what is the size of the largest matching.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks